# Is any character superior?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I understand this question invites discussion.

What I meant to ask was if due to

- basic stats (which I am unaware of)
- a certain item unlocked throughout the run specific to the character
- some other mechanism

one character is technically superior and intended to be used to learn the game and make the runs easier, whereas the others require a better knowledge and higher skill to take advantage of them.

Is there any particular characteristic that makes one of the characters the "easiest" to beat the game with?

Comment: Hello Lightbringer. Welcome to Arqade. I've reformatted your question. Since Arqade has a [revision history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/276597/revisions) (click on "edited X ago"), signalling your edits is not required. Placing edits at the bottom often impairs the readability, so try to avoid that in the future.

Comment: Ok, I was unaware of this. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: archer is best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no superior characters (or "Gungeoneers") in Enter the Gungeon; each one has strengths and weaknesses that give them a varying amount of success depending on your playstyle. So instead of making claims about which character is "best", I'll give a brief summary of each character's strengths and weaknesses.

## **The Marine**

- Main pistol has longest range of all "basic" Gungeoneers
- Starts with Military Training, which provides high gun accuracy
- The active item gives one free ammo drop
- Starts with 1 armor, so he can take one more hit than any other character

Summary: The Marine is usually considered the "beginner" character, since his high accuracy and long range make aiming a little easier in hectic fights. His extra ammo crate is immensely helpful to replenish the ammo on your best gun, and the extra armor is a nice benefit as well.

## **The Convict**

- Sawed-Off shotgun is good for burst or AoE damage.
- Molotov is also good for AoE damage, provided you don't step in the fire yourself.
- Enraging Photo compensates you when you get hit by providing a little more damage
- Both her starting pistol and the shotgun have somewhat short range

The Convict seems to specialize in doing damage to multiple enemies at once. Her short range is offset by the fact that her damage is amplified significantly for a few seconds after getting hit. I personally find her to be the most challenging of characters, but she has a lot of power behind her.

## **The Hunter**

- Crossbow can one-shot most of the weak enemies for floors 1-2.
- The Dog gives free pickups (ammo, keys, hearts, blanks) (average about one or two items per floor)

The Hunter excels at clearing out the weak enemies so she can focus on killing the tougher baddies. Her crossbow does a decent amount of damage, so it's also not bad for bossing. Her dog provides much needed resources as the game progresses.

## **The Pilot**

- Can carry two active items at once
- Items in shops don't cost as much (about 15% cheaper)
- Trusty Lockpick has a 50% chance to open any locks without using a key.

  - If the Lockpick fails, you cannot open that lock, even with a key.
- Starting pistol is short-ish range and not very accurate.

Ah, the pilot. I have a love-hate relationship with this character. Because of his lockpicks, he can potentially open a bunch of chests that you would normally skip, meaning you will have more guns/items available to you, making you that much stronger. On the other hand, failing to pick a lock will make a chest inaccessible. His shop discount also allows him to buy a few more items than other characters, further increasing his power. However, the first floor or two is really painful due to his wildly inaccurate starter pistol. This character is a high-risk, high-reward Gungeoneer who scales really well into the late game but struggles early.

## **The Cultist**

- Only accessible if you're playing co-op
- Friendship Cookie brings one player back to life
- Starter pistol has longest range of any other starting pistol

This character is only available when playing Co-op. He's pretty average and makes a decent companion.

## Secret Character spoilers below

> **The Bullet**

- Main weapon can erase bullets
- Does not take contact damage
- Can deal increased damage by dodge-rolling into enemies.

This guy is my favorite character because he has a very unique style of gameplay. His main weapon, Blasphemy, is a sword that erases bullets when he swings at them. If he is at full health, the sword will also fire a sword beam projectile (a la Legend of Zelda). If you position yourself correctly, you can hit enemies with both the sword slash and the projectile, doing a ton of damage to them in the process (you can one-shot regular bulletkin up to floor 4). Additionally, his complete immunity to contact damage makes certain enemies (especially jammed enemies) much easier to defeat. However, this strength comes with a price: If this character ever has less than full health (armor not included), his sword will not fire the projectile... and on early floors when you have no other guns, that forces you to fight enemies using melee attacks, which can be difficult for some players. I've seen this character described as simultaneously the easiest and hardest character in the game.

> **The Robot**

- Very long range starter weapon
- Starts with Battery Bullets, which increases accuracy with all weapons by 50% and shocks any water on the floor
- His active item drops lots of water on the floor
- Cannot gain health, only armor

In my opinion, this character is the toughest Gungeoneer. Though he excels at AoE damage (due to his active item and Battery Bullets), the fact that he can only gain armor means he is very vulnerable to being hit. You have to be pretty good at the game to be able to win with this guy.

Comment: This is actually a great answer. Funny thing I already put in over 100 hours into the game, so I answered the question myself, but you sir deserve a +1 for the effort. I would only add to your answer that the Bullet is easily the best character for speed-running, due to its high damage and clearance capacity when compared with the other gungeoneer's starting weapons.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you liked the answer. I agree, the Bullet is very good for speedrunning... assuming you don't get hit. His damage is pretty lackluster without the extra projectile, and because he has to be in melee range at that point, certain enemies (bosses especially) can get pretty dicey. That said, I've played a whole run (from start to killing the Past) using only Blasphemy, so it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't even played the game so I'm unsure as to why I'm attempting to answer this question, so I've used someone else's answer to the same question, answer is on a [Steam Community Form](https://steamcommunity.com/app/311690/discussions/0/371919771751855147/)

> If your playstyle is cautious and you dislike taking hits, then you should try the Pilot or Hunter. The Convict is buffed if she takes hits and Marine gets an extra armor, which is probably not what you want.
>
> The Pilot has better shops and is good in the long run, but you need to rely on your guns because his starting weapon is trash. He can also pick up two active items, which can be pretty useful.
>
> The Hunter can get extra items (including keys, and ammo) which is pretty nice. She dosen't (sic) get an active but her crossbow one-shots the weak mooks on chambers 1 and 2. This makes her good for the early game.
>
> -Empathy, Steam ID : 76561198041783823 incase you want to thank him or something

Comment: Where did you pull this from?  You should be linking it, at the very least.  You also need to look into providing attribution on a regular basis if you're copying from elsewhere.  It's good etiquette, at the very least, and gives credit where it's due.

Comment: Was working on adding a link while you were typing that comment :P

Comment: I am not looking for opinions, I apologize for the poor formulation of my question, but this does not help.